# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when updating view

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-ng-if

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

when I try to update the view (toggle on an icon display) using *ngIf.

Here is my .ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-orders',
    templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class OrdersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    loadedPendingOrders: Order[] = [];
    loadedProcessedOrders: Order[] = [];
    loadedDeliveredOrders: Order[] = [];
    loadedCancelledOrders: Order[] = [];
    pendingOrderTimelines: string[] = [];
    deliveredOrderTimelines: string[] = [];
    cancelledOrderTimelines: string[] = [];
    isDeliverySlotsActive: boolean;
    searchTerm: string;
    newOrderStatus: string;
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private ordersService: OrdersManagerService, private shopPreferencesService: ShopManagerService, private apiManager: ApiManagerService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.apiManager.fetchShopOrders())
            ).subscribe(orders => {
                this.isDeliverySlotsActive = this.shopPreferencesService.isDeliverySlotsActive();
                const loadedOrders: OrdersList = orders;
                /* do stuff with orders */
        });
    }

    onNewOrderAdded(status: string){
        this.newOrderStatus = status;
    }
    ....
}
```

And here is my .html:

```
<div id="tab-group">
    <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight animationDuration="400ms">
        <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <span>Pending</span>
                <img src="../../assets/my-orders/blue-tiny.svg" *ngIf="newOrderStatus == 'PENDING'">
            </ng-template>
            <app-orders-list
                [orders]="loadedPendingOrders"
                [timelines]="pendingOrderTimelines"
                [isDeliverySlotsActive]="isDeliverySlotsActive"
                [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
                (newOrderStatus)="onNewOrderAdded($event)"
            ></app-orders-list>
            ...
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

The view is being updated correctly. However, the error is still being thrown. How come?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the stack trace of the error should point you to the specific value in the template that's triggering the error. I have a feeling this is caused by the `dynamicHeight` directive but without the code its just a guess. which one is it ?

Comment: @Stavm It's pointing to this line: `<img src="../../assets/my-orders/blue-tiny.svg" *ngIf="newOrderStatus === 'PENDING'">`

Comment: @Stavmn I've updated the question with a pic of the error. Will check if it's because of `dynamicHeight` right now.

Comment: @Stavm Removing `dynamicHeight` didn't fix it. It's a weird error because the view is updating correctly, but the error is still being thrown nonetheless.

Comment: can you try removing `(newOrderStatus)="onNewOrderAdded($event)"` see if it happens

Comment: @Stavm The error goes away when I remove that but the view is not updated, obviously.

Comment: can you add `OrdersListComponent` code. it seems that it executes `this.newOrderStatus.next(...)` where it shouldn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232180/discussion-between-manuel-bras-and-stavm).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are changing `newOrderStatus` before the component lifecycle has completed. The value starts as `undefined`, then you pass some data to the child, which then emits the next value back to the parent.

This is typically a code smell in Angular apps. Your child is dictating the state of the parent, which should know its state.

[Here's a contrived example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-adsh4n?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.html) My parent component passes some value to the child, who then decides on some string value, emits it, which the parent then consumes to decide which `div` to display. Open the console to see the dreaded `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

To fix this issue I recommend separating your state and how it's computed (i.e. the status, the orders, etc) from your components (your Orders and OrdersList components). I would implement a service that has some functions for manipulating the state and an observable that emits the that components can subscribe to.

Comment: Yep, it's exactly the scenario you described. I appreciate your suggestions, but what are your thoughts on doing `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` in `ngAfterViewChecked`? I've been reading more about this error and this suggestion seems to come up quite often. I've tried it and it works but I have a suspicion it's the worst possible way of dealing with this... What's the least painful solution for a newbie junior dev like me?

Comment: I've definitely used it myself and it will likely make the error go away. In fact, that error does not even show up when you build with the --prod flag. It's really just a warning that something _might_ not be working correctly. However, like I said in my post it's definitely a code smell. I still think a little refactoring would go a long way and result in more maintainable and testable code.